# How can I configure a Django website to work with Apache 2.4 VirtualHosts?

Tags: centos, virtualhost, apache-2.4, vps, django

I recently started developing Django websites and I want to deploy them on a CentOS VPS with mod_wsgi and Apache.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7) and it works perfectly, but I would like to have more than one Django website running at the same time, so I tried to create multiple virtual hosts inside a proper config file, and there comes the problem.

```
<VirtualHost the.ip.of.server:80>
    ErrorLog /root/praxis.error.log

    Alias /static /root/Praxis/static
    <Directory /root/Praxis/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/Praxis/Praxis>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess Praxis python-path=/root/Praxis:/root/Env/Praxis/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup Praxis
    WSGIScriptAlias /praxis /root/Praxis/Praxis/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

**If I delete the VirtualHost opening and closing tag the site will work as expected, but if I keep those tags I will constantly receive a 404 error.**

I really don't understand why everything works fine only without tags.

I also tried to switch between IP-based virtual hosting and name-based virtual hosting but nothing changed.

Here follows also wsgi.py

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/root/Praxis/Praxis')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/root/Praxis/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Praxis.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In my **httpd.conf** file I also have:

```
Listen 80

ServerName ip.to.the.server #without port specified
```

and

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80 <-- THIS IS A COMMENT RIGHT NOW
```

Thank you all in advance for the effort, I hope someone will be able to help me, I'm struggling with this so hard! Thank you guys.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum. Answers belong in the Answers section below, not in your question where they can be missed.